# SVG elements are not shown in a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have faced to a quite strange situation. I have a script which draws some lines using jQuery SVG plugin. It is working in a separate html file. But once I copy that script and insert into another html file it stops showing SVG elements in a browser. It works perfectly, because when I see the source code of the page after running a script I could see that the script is adding SVG elements to the page. Here is SVG code of the page in any case:

```
<svg version="1.1">
  <line x1="492" y1="503" x2="717" y2="576" stroke="#4A4A4A" stroke-width="2"></line>
  <line x1="500" y1="400" x2="600" y2="400" stroke="#4A4A4A" stroke-width="2"></line>
  <line x1="604.5" y1="539.5" x2="587.5" y2="542.5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></line>
  <line x1="604.5" y1="539.5" x2="592.5" y2="527.5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></line>
</svg>
```

What could be the problem the those SVG elements are not shown in the browser? Have anybody else faced such a strange situation?

Comment: Yes knowing which browser you're using is pretty important, because not all of them support SVG.  (I'll let the suspense build on that one.)

Comment: It would also be helpful to know more about this other html file.  Exactly where in the file is the SVG being created?  What are the CSS rules, etc etc?

Comment: I use chrome. The problem is not in the browser I think, because it shows me the first html page with SVG in Chrome but when I open the second html page it doesn't show even though it has in a source code those svg elements.

Comment: Well it also works fine for me, so it's got to be something about the new page and/or it's CSS (or JavaScript for that matter).

Comment: does adding a doctype works if not already added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I didn't notice that in the new page where SVG elements were not shown, the DIV element where I was drawing SVG elements had been wrapped by another DIV. And in the CSS file the wrapper DIV had an attribute `display: table;`. I removed that attribute and now SVG elements are shown. Thanks guys for you help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the SVG namespace tag to your page?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `viewBox` attribute to the svg element to ensure that the coordinate system makes the lines appear within the svg viewport. Or make sure that in both documents size of the svg element is the same. My guess is that in one document the svg is quite wide, and in the other it's not as wide (thus clipping away the lines).